# Slicing Tools for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, slice

Does anyone know if there are any open source tools for eclipse that can generate static program slices according to the slicing technique outlined by Mark Weiser (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_slicing)? I can only seem to find JSlice, which only works for Fedora. Any pointers about how I could tackle this (and libraries out there, or example algorithms for java) would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I haven't tried the tool listed below.

---

[Indus](http://indus.projects.cis.ksu.edu/). It appears to make itself useful via the [Kaveri plugin](http://indus.projects.cis.ksu.edu/projects/kaveri.shtml) in Eclipse.

---

It would be worth noting that apart from JSlice and Indus, no other known code slicers for Java appear to be available, although there are quite a few papers that discuss building a code slicer for Java. Sadly, the authors do not appear to have made these tools available for further research.

Comment: I would be inclined to agree! Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 1):

How about [WALA](http://wala.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/UserGuide:Slicer) and [javaslicer](https://github.com/hammacher/javaslicer).